# Console object is not accessible in IE11 (Permission denied)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11, permission-denied

We have faced a weird issue in IE11. During initialization of the page, initialization code of Dojo script uses `console` object, and accessing this object causes `Permission denied` error that fails whole initialization.

[image: Console permission denied]

Meanwhile the `navigator` object has the same issues. The IE11 build is Release Preview and that should be the reasons of these issues. However, the build has the same version as the released one and all updates are installed.

[image: IE11]

It might be some settings issues, but changing it gave no effects.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you sure `this` there is the correct instance? I couldn't  reproduce this bug even in my Developer Channel version.

Comment: @VitorCanova Thank you very much for your efforts. Yes, `this` is correct instance, the same happens if I try `window.console` - it knows the object exists but does not allow any actions with it. Now I think that maybe during IE updates something gone wrong, because I don't have any other explanations for it.

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear, this Release Preview is a old version right? Not an upcoming one?

Comment: @VitorCanova Yes, an old one.